# cocoa osx add nstextfields programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, constraints, nsview, nstextfield

I'm making a project for osx and I need to add multiple NSTextfields to a custom view (NSView) programmatically. I don't know how to achieve this correctly.

This is what I need to do:

[image]

I know how to create the NSTextfiedls and how to add them to the NSView, but i dont know how to config them to show like in the image and set them any constraints in code. I'm using autolayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using the `NSStackView` class to hold your text fields. For simple set-ups - like the one in your screenshot - this class does the auto-layout work for you.

[image]

To help you get to grips with it, Apple provide a sample demo called [InforBarStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/InfoBarStackView/Introduction/Intro.html) .

---

The screenshot below is from a program which added a stack view instance to an otherwise empty window in Interface Builder.

[image]

The text fields were added with the following code:

```
// AppDelegate has a stackView outlet
for each in 0...2 {
    var f = NSTextField()
    f.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.addView(f, inGravity:.Top)
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to use stackview. Could you post a more complex example? With stackview can i add multiple items without limit?

Comment: *Could you post a more complex example?* - have updated post to provide a link to an Apple demo showcasing the ``NSStackView``. *Can I add multiple items with limit?* - questions like this are best answered by the documentation for the class. From what I can see the ``NSStackView`` class reference mentions to limit on the subviews it can handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the frames for each Text field. 
like

```
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(xPos,SuperView.frame.size.height - (padding + control_Height),control_Width,control_Height);
`for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
{

NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[superView addSubView:textField];
[textField release];
rect.origin.y -= (padding + control_Height);

}`
```